# How to set the default intent?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I find that if I have just one intent (in addition to the built-in intents), no matter what utterance is spoken, it will always invoke the endpoint with `request.intent.name` matching the name of that one intent.

If I have more than one intent configured, if the utterance spoken does not match any of the sample utterances of any of the intents, one of the intents will be selected. It seems to be always the same one for each build. I don't know how this "default" intent is selected.

How do I select one intent to be the default, or make it go to `AMAZON.HelpIntent`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as far as I understand, what happens is that the triggered intent is chosen like the best candidate, based on the utterances that are pretty close to what Alexa understood.

Not sure if you have, for example, a FallBackIntent. Also you can try adding an ExceptionHandler.

There is no way to select a default intent.

I hope this shines a light on the right path to clarify your doubt.

Comment: `AMAZON.FallbackIntent` is the answer.